# How to delete composite child nodes from a VBox when the event occurs in the composite child itself?

Tags: java, javafx, vbox

I have a root node of VBox.
I also have a composite node that created using Pane and button within it.
Multiple Instances of the composite node are added to the VBox.
I tried to find a way to remove each composite node when its inner button is fired.
But i failed to finding a way.
Here is my code, Can anybody help me please?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    root.setSpacing(10);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 700);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    // 10 Non reffered instances will be added to the VBox(root)
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Pane compositeChild = new Pane();
        compositeChild.setPrefWidth(300);
        compositeChild.setPrefHeight(40);
        compositeChild.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.CORAL, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
        Button btn = new Button("Delete Me");
        btn.setPrefWidth(200);
        btn.setPrefHeight(30);
        btn.setLayoutX(50);
        btn.setLayoutY(5);

        // I want to find some code for below action event
        btn.setOnAction(e2 -> {
            //how can I remove only one compositeChild that the event fired From the root(VBox)
            ((Button)e2.getSource()).setText("I should be deleted??");
        });

        compositeChild.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(compositeChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
btn.setOnAction(e2 -> {
    root.getChildren().remove(compositeChild);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
btn.setOnAction(e2 ->
{
    if (btn.getParent() == null || btn.getParent().getParent() == null)
        return;

    ((Pane)btn.getParent().getParent()).getChildren().remove(btn.getParent());
});
```

Comment: I've seen code like this before, but never really understood why you would do this. If you do `btn.setOnAction(e2 -> { ... });`, then you *know* what `e2.getSource()` is going to return: it must return `btn`. So why call the method and perform the cast? It just makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: @James_D You do have a point there. It sets me thinking about the differences writing (potentially) reusable event handlers vs lambda expressions (which can never be reused).

Comment: In your edited version, I could also point out that in this situation you know that `btn.getParent()` is `compositeChild`, and that `compositeChild.getParent()` is `root`... but I won't belabor the point ;). More seriously, I've generally found that event handlers are so specific to the task, there's almost never any chance for reuse anyway, so I tend to keep them short and to the point and not try to make them general. JMO of course.

Comment: @James_D Well, it is true that it `btn.getParent()` and `btn.getParent().getParent()` would get those 2 objects, but writing it this way is slightly more resistant to changes; if one year down the road he decides to add an extra `Parent` in between the composite and the root, at least this would not break.

Comment: Sorry, I was tires and had some sleep. That's why I couldn't participate your conversation. Have you solved your casting problem? Anyway Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Jai I have edited your answer a little.
I altered btn.getParent().getParent() to ((Pane)btn.getParent().getParent()) adding some casting. Now the code is working as we expected! Thanks again!